# Android disable audio system pop up

Tags: android, audio

I try to do the same as snapchat/instagram audio control when video playing.

I'm on API21+

How can I disable audio system popup ? and still intercept command

I can do this but not working if you control sound from other way than sound touch

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) + 1, 0);
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) - 1, 0);
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

I try this but it's not working

```
mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int i) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAudioFocusChange: " + i);
            MediaSessionCompat sessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "TAG");
            sessionCompat.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onMediaButtonEvent: " + mediaButtonEvent);
                    return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
                }
            });
            sessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
            sessionCompat.setPlaybackToRemote(new VolumeProviderCompat(VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_FIXED, 15, 5) {
                @Override
                public void onSetVolumeTo(int volume) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSetVolumeTo: ");
                    super.onSetVolumeTo(volume);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdjustVolume(int direction) {
                    super.onAdjustVolume(direction);
                }

                @Override
                public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
                    super.setCallback(callback);
                }
            });
            sessionCompat.setActive(true);
        }
    }, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```